# Create a jquery slider dynamic

Tags: jquery, slider

I used the easy slider in the page, but i want to put another slider in the same page . now i have problem if i use the div with same ID or class it is not work.

example:-

```
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>        
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
```

if i use the same class in the same page, it didn't work. plz help me how to manage  the same slider more times in the same page.

Comment: Hiya, where is the Jquery code you tried man?

Comment: Made a small sample for you much simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/DC6ZM/ :) (not easy slider) cheerios!

Comment: you can't have the same `id` in HTML. If you could it would be **IDentification**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this method in your JavaScript code,

```
$("#slider").easySlider({
     auto: true,
     continuous: true 
});
```

Then create

```
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <ul>        
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider_new" class="slider">
  <ul>        
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then add the slide JavaScript two times like,

```
$("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true 
});
$("#slider_new").easySlider({
    auto: true,
    continuous: true 
});
```

This should work.
I am assuming that you are using [this](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)